# How to update links on SharePoint Online Modern Text Editor, dynamically on many pages within site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, text-webpart, modern-sharepoint

I have many Pages in SharePoint Online, with modern text editor having many document links pointing to Document library within same Site Collection. Now we are planning to move documents into multiple document library based on some classification. Hence we want to update the existing URL with new URL. Is there a way to update links without editing each page manually and update?

Here is an example of a page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly have considered using Document IDs so URLs to documents are kept even when moved to another library or site.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/activate-and-configure-document-ids-in-a-site-collection-66345c77-f079-4104-ac7a-e25826849306?ocmsassetid=ha102773259&correlationid=5a81a8b7-0220-4602-8f89-61efa7bd5744&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

However, assuming you haven't done so, you can use PnP.PowerShell to build a script that iterates SharePoint Online site pages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets

```
# define which site collection you want to run the script on
$siteCollectionUrl = ""

# replacement hastable where the key is the old document url and the value is the new document url
$replacementlist = @{"https://olddocumenturl" = "https://newdocumenturl"}

# Connect to SharePoint site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteCollectionUrl -Interactive

# Get list items
$pages = Get-PnPListItem -List "Site Pages" 

# Iterate list items
foreach($page in $pages) {
   # do work
}
```

On every page you must iterate the page controls and look for the `PageText` type, and then some additional logic to replace the actual URLs before saving and re-publishing the page.

Hopefully this is helpful and can get you started.